# Code processes only the first of 14 lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer

I am trying to find the difference between the rows `w` and the columns `h`. 
The code only proceses the first line.

```
output = []
with open(r'input-text.txt', 'r') as f:
    w, h  = map(int, f.readline().split())
    tmp = []
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == h:
            break
        tmp.append(map(int, line.split()[:h]))
    output.append(tmp)


    print(h - w)
```

**input-text.txt**

```
132 210
48 60
50 82
```

Comment: What was the result of your own debugging? What were the values of `w`, `h`, `i` throughout the program?

Comment: The title mentions 14 lines, but the example file in the question has only 3 lines. Please clarify what exactly you mean.

Comment: What leads you to the conclusion that the code only processes the first line? What output do you get and what did you expect to get instead?

Comment: @mkrieger1 What leads you to the conclusion that the code only processes the first line? What output do you get and what did you expect to get instead?

because the output is always the difference betwen whatever is on the first line  no matter how many lines i put

Comment: @mkrieger1 The title mentions 14 lines, but the example file in the question has only 3 lines. Please clarify what exactly you mean 

yes i wish to proceses 14 line and i gave only 3 for simplification

Comment: @mkrieger1 What was the result of your own debugging? What were the values of w, h, i throughout the program?

honestly I am still a beginner i don't know how to debug, i don't have any background on programming i am tryin to learn by looking for code that does something close to what i want and i experiment with it change the values and see what happens it is a bad way to learn  i know but at least it is a start  and thank you btw for your comments

Comment: @mkrieger1 to clarify even more I have a GUI app that has Student Grades for two semesters, so I have a mini code that takes a screenshot than the screenshot is converted to text via OCR than it is saved into a text file.
 now I want to access the file and find out the difference between the first semester grade and the second semester grade each line represents a student
Ex: 200 186 
186 is the grade of the first semester  200 is the grade of the second, the whole line is specific to one student I would love to find the difference between the two grades and I have 14 students

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simplify the code a bit.

```
output = []
with open('input-text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()
        output.append(int(data[1]) - int(data[0]))

print(output)
```

This results in a list such that the second value on each line is subtracted from the first value on each line:

```
[78, 12, 32]
```

In case you're looking for the total of all values in columns 'h' and 'w':

```
h, w = 0, 0
with open('input-text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()
        w += int(data[1])
        h += int(data[0])

print(w - h)
```

Which returns the output:

```
122
```

Comment: for the first code i get this error 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\BOT\tst.py", line 5, in <module>
    output.append(int(data[1]) - int(data[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: for the second one i get this error 

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\BOT\tst.py", line 5, in <module>
    w += int(data[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Then your input-text file probably does not match what was posted in the original question. If you have a comma between the values or any other formatting other than a strict copy-paste, it may not split properly.

Comment: indeed i had a comma in my text file 
now that i have a list how can I write it in a nother text file and have each value of the list in it's seperate line + is it possible afterwards to take a value from the new text file and have the programme do things 

Ex: 150 100
output will be 50 
than python writes 50 in a new text file 
than i read from the new text file 
and if the value is above 50 let's say it executes a method
and if the value i lower than 50 it executes another method

Comment: Everything you're asking is possible and pretty simple, but you're asking for a lot of different things. I'd recommend reading up on input/output files at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html specifically section 7.2. There are probably easier, more efficient ways to accomplish what you're asking without even writing to a text file unless that's absolutely necessary. Try to clearly write out what you are trying to accomplish, and the exact steps you have to take to accomplish it. Then write your script step-by-step.